# how to get only number between parenthesis by using python

Tags: python, regex

this is text : 에코프로비엠 (247540/매수)대장님 먼저 24년으로 가겠습니다

i want to get only 247540

```
result = re.search(r"\(([0-9]+)\)", link.text)
print(result, link.text)
```

It return None.

this is full code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = r"https://securities.miraeasset.com/bbs/board/message/list.do?categoryId=1545"

response = requests.get(url)

if response.status_code == 200:
    html = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    link = soup.select_one("#bbsTitle0")
    href = link.get("href")[16:-1].replace("'", "")
    arr = list(map(int, href.split(",")))
    linkPage = r"https://securities.miraeasset.com/bbs/board/message/view.do?messageId={0}&messageNumber={1}&messageCategoryId=0&startId=zzzzz~&startPage=1&curPage=2&searchType=2&searchText=&searchStartYear=2020&searchStartMonth=09&searchStartDay=10&searchEndYear=2021&searchEndMonth=09&searchEndDay=10&lastPageFlag=&vf_headerTitle=&categoryId=1545".format(
        arr[0], arr[1]
    )
    result = re.search(r"\(([0-9]+)\)", link.text)
    print(result.group(1), link.text)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are trying to match with `\(([0-9]+)\)` is strictly the text `(247540)` when in reality there are additional characters after the number `(247540/매수)`. Thus, you should also match the next characters after the number. So try:

```
\(([0-9]+).*?\)
```

Or if you are also expecting the digits might be in the middle of the parenthesis and not actually the start:

```
\(.*?([0-9]+).*?\)
```

**Sample Run:**

[image]

Where:

- `\(` - Match the opening parenthesis
- `.*?` - Match any characters in a non-greedy way
- `([0-9]+)` - Capture 1 or more digits. Since the previous pattern is non-greedy, this will capture as much consecutive digits as possible.
- `.*?` - Match any characters in a non-greedy way
- `\)` - Match the closing parenthesis. Since the previous pattern is non-greedy, this will match the closest parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

`link.text.split("(")[-1].split("/")[0]`

Comment: I think this is too specific to the example. Suppose there are other `(` in the text or no `/` following the digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string function isdigit() to seperate out integers.

```
result_final=""
for i in result:
    if i.isdigit()==True:
        result_final+=i
print(result_final)
```